# Visual Studio 2017 - Solution Explorer folders collapse when opening project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, directory, solution-explorer

When I open a previously opened solution, all the folders in Solution Explorer are collapsed. VS 2013 didn't do this - the folder tree was as it was when the project was closed.

I tried deleting my .suo file as offered in another thread but that does not work.

Is there a way to set 2017 to keep SE folder structure/openness from a previous session in tact?